# Using IPC to redirect stdin within a while loop

Tags: c, ipc, stdin

I'm trying to write a string to clipboard on linux with C. I plan to use `xsel -ib` (takes a string from standard input and sets it as the current clipboard content). For example, in bash, doing `echo Hello world | xsel -ib` would set "Hello World" into the clipbord.

My code consists of a simple IPC that works well when my program (parent) finishes execution, but it doesn't work if I wrap the IPC inside a while loop.

```
#include<unistd.h>
void main()
{
    while (1) { // 1
        int pipes[2] = { 0 };
        pipe(pipes);
        if (fork()) {
            close(pipes[0]);
            write(pipes[1], "hello world", sizeof("hello world"));
        } else {
            close(0);
            dup2(pipes[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(pipes[1]);
            execl("/usr/bin/xsel", "xsel", "-ib", NULL);
        }
        printf("\nTesting..");
        sleep(3); // 2
    } // 3
}
```

If I remove the lines commented by "1", "2" and "3", it works fine. But having a while loop is essential for me to be able to output different strings to the clipboard every now and then. How do I do this without terminating my program.

Comment: You're leaking an unclosed file descriptor in the parent. The child doesn't get `EOF`, because the file is not closed in the parent, and thus doesn't terminate. Eventually you'll run out of file descriptors, or `fork()` will fail due to the maximum number of user processes being reached.

Comment: First of all you should really be checking for errors from all system calls. Secondly, you should [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for the child process in the parent. Thirdly, and no big deal, but you you don't need to `close` the standard input file descriptor, it will be done by the [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) call (you should be closing `pipes[0]` though after the `dup2` call).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the program you show "doesn't work"? *How* doesn't it work? Do you get build errors? Runtime crashes? Unexpected results? Something else?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Like @EOF said, I believe the child does not seem to get EOF or something. The clipboard doesn't get set to "hello world". More importantly, the program doesn't print the `Testing...` line at all.

Comment: @Power-Inside The child isn't getting EOF because the stream isn't closed in the parent - it doesn't see the end because there is no end.  Add `close(pipes[1])` after your `write()` call.  Also, see the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) for `popen()` if you want to try a simpler solution.

Comment: @EOF That EOF problem seems to be what the OP is having trouble with, why don't you write that as an answer that the OP can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few small changes that should make the program more debuggable, and fix at least some of the issues.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main() /*correct declaration is int main()...*/
{
    while (1) { // 1
        int pipes[2] = { 0 };
        if (pipe(pipes)){
            perror("pipe() failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1){
            perror("fork() failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pid) {
            close(pipes[0]);
            write(pipes[1], "hello world", sizeof("hello world"));
            close(pipes[1]);
/*prevents file descriptor leak, also causes a read() to signal EOF rather than block indefinitely*/
            int status;
            wait(&status); /*prevents child zombification*/

        } else {
            close(0);
            dup2(pipes[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(pipes[1]);
            execl("/usr/bin/xsel", "xsel", "-ib", NULL);
        }
        printf("\nTesting..");
        sleep(3); // 2
    } // 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. All I needed was the missing `close(pipes[1])`. (I did have the error checking for system calls in my original code. Just removed it to make my snippet smaller). I'm new to IPC and coming back to C after a long time. :)